# Hyperlink to a frame

Tags: html, hyperlink, frame

I have:

```
1. page "a.hmtl"
2. page "b.hmtl" and frame "b1" with page "bb.html" 
3. page "cc.html"
```

I'm on page "a.html" and want to make hyperlink to page's "b.hmtl" frame "b1" with page "cc.html". How to solve a problem?

Comment: What did you tried so far? Please put the code here. Let's know what exactly your problem is.

Comment: I want to add hyperlink to html file, that would open in another html file's frame. Is to posible to write such code?
I think it should be somethink like this: 
<a target="_CODE" href="b1.html" CODE{frame code}"cc.html">

Comment: I read it twice and still don't catch you... Can you give us a full example of what you're trying to do and the expected flow? Also, please *provide your code indicating where you're stuck*

Comment: Justinai, lietuviškai turbūt paaiškinti bus paprasčiau. Noriu sukurti nuorodą į kito puslapio frame'ą. Esu A puslapyje, noriu, kad nukeltų į B puslapį, kuriame yra frame, su konkrečiu puslapiu tame frame. Man reikia, kad aš galėčiau pasirinkti koks bus puslapis tame frame. Galiu naudot JS.